# Swift3 - How to access variables in closure

Tags: json, swift3, closures

Im trying to access the variable `pic` after the request is made but its in a closure, thats why `print(pic)` doesn't work.

How would someone go about accessing this?

```
guard let url = URL(string: "myurl") else{ return }
    var pic = ""
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
        if let data = data {
            print(data)
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let parseJSON = json {
                    pic = parseJSON["picture"] as! String
                    print(json!)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        }.resume()

  print(pic)
}
```

Comment: You have to declare a variable outside the scope of the closure and assign the value inside the closure to this variable. However, since you are dealing with a network request, the closure is actually a completion handler, that doesn't return immediately, only after the asynchronous request finished, so printing the value right after the completion block still wouldn't work. Have a look into how completion handlers and asynchronous functions work in Swift

Comment: It is a timing issue. The `print(pic)` statement is performed before the asynchronous completion handler closure of `dataTask` has had a chance to run yet. Bottom line, remember that the closure runs asynchronously, so don't try to use the results immediately outside of the closure. Usually you'd dispatch UI updates to the main queue from within the closure or, better, adopt completion handler pattern yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pic is an image you'll be loading into a `UIImageView`:

You can add an Activity Indicator to your ImageView.  Then when you call your function to download the pic simply add:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "myurl") else{ return }
activityIndicator.isHidden = false
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

The user will know a download is occurring.  When complete,

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
activityIndicator.isHidden = true
activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "pic")
}
   }.resume
```

Dispatching on the main que will update the UI immediately.

Comment: If you're going to update UI from within `dataTask` completion handler closure, make sure to dispatch those UI updates to the main queue.

Comment: Just adding that.  sorry.